# Return notable_for in mql

Tags: freebase

My code:

```
[{
  "id": null,
  "name": null,
  "/common/topic/alias": [],
  "/common/topic/notable_for": [],
  "limit": 100,
  "type": "/sports/sport"
}]
```

[Link](http://tinyurl.com/oq7etlr)

`"/common/topic/alias"` is returned fine however `notable_for` is always empty. I also tried: `null`, `[{}]`,  `{}` and `/common/notable_for` which gives a schema error.

How can I return the `notable_for` value per instance in the `/sports/sport` example above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notable_for data is computed separately from other facts in Freebase and is not accessible  from the MQL API. It is however available from the [Search API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-overview), the [Topic API](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/topic-overview) and the [RDF data dumps](https://developers.google.com/freebase/data).

**Search API:**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?filter=(all+type:/sports/sport)&output=(/common/topic/alias)
```

**Topic API:**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/071k0
```